# Group grep command

Tags: grep

I would like to `grep` file names that do not start with `s` and that contains a `m`.

I tried this solution that works:

```
ls | grep -Ev "^s" | grep "m"
```

But when I try to do it with a single `grep` command, it fails:

```
ls | grep -E '^[^s]*m*'
```

I cannot explain why. Is it possible to do it with only one `grep` command?

Comment: Question: can the filename also start with an `m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the `*` incorrectly in your regular expression.

The specification (cf. also the man-page of grep) states that

```
*      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
```

Your regular expression would therefore mean:
"Match any filename starting with anything but the letter `s`, and this zero or more times, and then zero or more times the letter `m`."

The regular expression should instead read

```
ls | grep -E '^[^s][[:alnum:]]*m'
```

i.e. you must indicate *what* symbol should be present zero or more times before the 'm', in your case any alphanumerical character should be ok. If your filenames can contain `-` or `_`, then replace `[[:alnum:]]` with `[[:print:]]`.

As an extreme case, if your filename can also *start* with an `m`, the regexp would be

```
ls | grep -E '(^m|^[^s][[:print:]]*m)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `grep` for this.

```
printf '%s\n' [!s]*m*
```

Testing:

```
$ touch small big larger enormous much
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 24 13:20 big
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 24 13:20 enormous
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 24 13:20 larger
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 24 13:20 much
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 24 13:20 small
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' [!s]*m*
enormous
```

The filename globbing pattern `[!s]*m*` expands to all files that does not start with an `s` but that contains an `m`.

This would however not find filenames that contains `m` only as the first character.

For that, you could glob for files that don't start with `m` or `s` but contain `m`, and files that start with `m`, separately.  This is a bit more fiddly to maintain and it's not immediately clear what it does from reading the code:

```
$ printf '%s\n' [!ms]*m* m*
enormous
much
```

Or, use `find`, which IMHO, is easier to read:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[!s]*' -name '*m*'
./enormous
./much
```

Comment: @rastafile If he wanted to grep a list of files then he wouldn't have tried to parse `ls`. If it's a file with alphanumeric characters then either `printf` or `find` will work.

Comment: @NasirRiley  I mean lines as contents of a file. Could be a file containing names. Then you would want to `grep "..." names.txt`. Whoever is behind these avatars, he never understands this. Just this reflex "dont parse". Starts with silly Qs, of course. But instead of clearing, it you make a huge mess.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`. With that aside, I'm going to answer your question regarding `grep`.

If you insist on using `grep` then what you want is this:

```
grep -E "^[a-rt-zA-RT-Z][[:alnum:]]*m" file
```

In fact, it even works without `-E`:

```
grep "^[a-rt-zA-RT-Z][[:alnum:]]*m" file
```

That will print anything beginning with anything other than `s` or `S` and then any alphanumeric character which includes `m`, and any characters after that whether they are `m` or not. In effect, it gives the output that you are looking for.

As you are working with files, the first `printf` solution above is far better as it doesn't require the parsing of `ls`. You can use the `grep` above with filenames but I would advise against it and recommend using it with the contents of files or data in standard output.

You can also use `find` for files as it doesn't need to be parsed:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*m*" -name "[!s]*"
```

Depending on your environment, you may need to escape the `*`

```
find /path/to directory -type f -name "\*m\*" -name "'[!s]\*"
```

Comment: for the regex, you don't need to list all the characters that aren't `s`. you can use a negated bracket expression - `^[^s]*m` (or `^[^sS]*m` for case-insensitive).